# Commands for russian morphemic analysis of the word

Tags: symbols

I would like to create commands for morphemic analysis of Russian words, equivalent to ones on attached images.

[image]
[image]

By now I wrote/googled/adapted commands for root, suffix and ending.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{n}{<->tipa10}{}
    \newcommand{\arc@char}{{\usefont{U}{tipa}{m}{n}\symbol{62}}}%

    \newcommand{\arc}[1]{\mathpalette\arc@arc{#1}}

    \newcommand{\arc@arc}[2]{%
      \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
      \vbox{
        \hbox{\resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\arc@char}}
        \nointerlineskip
        \box0
      }%
    }
\makeatother


\NewDocumentCommand{\ending}{ m }%
    {$\framebox[\widthof{#1}]{\vphantom{\scalebox{1.25}{#1}}#1}$}


\NewDocumentCommand{\emptyEnding}{}%
    {\Окончание{\phantom{o}}\singlespace}


\NewDocumentCommand{\suffix}{ m }%
    {$\widehat{\vphantom{\scalebox{1.15}{#1}}\text{#1}}$}


\NewDocumentCommand{\root}{ m }%
    {$\arc{\text{#1}}$}

\NewDocumentCommand{\singlespace}{}{\char32}
```

Could you please help with *prefix* command? And have a look at the other commands in case there are better ways to achieve what is needed?

Comment: Good question! One way to do this would surely be a TikZ diagram, but perhaps one of our users will pull off neat tricks in text mode. stacked `\scalebox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time creating something like a package for this task using TikZ as was suggested by @Davislor.

By now, the result I ended up with totally suits my needs.

You may want to have a look at my solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/Vezzp/RSLingu). I happened to write some instructions (text is in Russian, but with examples it is possible to get a clue of what is going on) demonstrating how to use the commands. Instructions are also available GitHub either as PDF or as `.tex` file.